# As a UK resident, what is the best way to use my Aeroflot miles which are expiring soon?

Tags: loyalty-programs, aeroflot

I have 42k of Aeroflot miles and now live in the UK, but unfortunately due to the Chinese pandemic restrictions, I didn't fly to China at all (on China Southern) in 2022 and 2023 and my miles are expiring soon.

I expected to be able to redeem my miles on a China Southern flight to Guangzhou but it is also no longer possible, and unfortunately Aeroflot no longer flies to London (an old way to fly between Europe and China is to change at Moscow as Aeroflot offered competitive fares, that's why I have got so many miles as it was always the cheapest), or anywhere further than Kaliningrad in Europe.

The information on partner redemption is also unclear, and its customer service has been slow responding to my queries this year. Can anyone advise me how I can get the best value out of my miles, either in UK or in China, which are going to expire next month?

Comment: With the sanctions currently in effect there are probably quite a large number of limitations both on flights and on partnerships. Note also that if they charge anything when you use your miles (e.g. taxes), as they seem to do, then you probably won't be able to pay for them.

Comment: I don't think UnionPay payments are sanctioned. It doesn't involve the western world.

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure https://www.newsweek.com/china-russia-unionpay-huawei-pay-sanctions-1874226 YMMV though.